# Pandas, extract information from dictionary column into a new column quickly

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary

I have a large df that has four columns. One of these columns has words, and another column has those words as keys of a dictionary. I need to add another column extracting the values for the word of interest. Example:

```
ID        ID2     words      dict1
x12_12    12984   apple      {'apple': 5, 'pear': 10}
x12_12    12984   pear       {'apple': 5, 'pear': 10}
x12_12    20934   orange     {'orange': 5, 'pear': NaN}
x12_12    20934   pear       {'orange': 5, 'pear': NaN}
```

I need to create a new column called value to extract the information from dict1

```
ID        ID2     words      dict1                         value
x12_12    12984   apple      {'apple': 5, 'pear': 10}      5
x12_12    12984   pear       {'apple': 5, 'pear': 10}      10
x12_12    20934   orange     {'orange': 20, 'pear': NaN}   20
x12_12    20934   pear       {'orange': 20, 'pear': NaN}   NaN
```

I have this code which gives me the desired result, but it takes a long time to run and I have a very large dataset. I know 'apply' is not the most efficient for large data.

```
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['dict1'][row['words']], axis=1)
```

Any suggestions for faster methods? I tried using np.vectorize but it has an issue with the nan values and I keep getting errors.

Comment: Pandas 2.2 added some useful [support to struct](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.2.0.html#series-struct-accessor-for-pyarrow-structured-data) for PyArrow structured data. They solve well these family of tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest option: use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
df['value'] = [d.get(w) for w,d in zip(df['words'], df['dict1'])]
```

Alternatively, combine [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['words'])

df['value'] = (pd.json_normalize(df['dict1'])
                 .reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
               [np.arange(len(df)), idx]
              )
```

Or with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['value'] = (df.groupby('words', as_index=False)['dict1']
                 .apply(lambda g: g.str[g.name]).droplevel(0)
              )
```

Output:

```
       ID    ID2   words                       dict1  value
0  x12_12  12984   apple    {'apple': 5, 'pear': 10}    5.0
1  x12_12  12984    pear    {'apple': 5, 'pear': 10}   10.0
2  x12_12  20934  orange  {'orange': 5, 'pear': nan}    5.0
3  x12_12  20934    pear  {'orange': 5, 'pear': nan}    NaN
```

###### Timings

On 400k rows. In the end the list comprehension is the fastest, which makes sense since the limiting steps are based on loops anyway. `apply` is a loop but has a large overhead due to creating a Series for each row. Always replace `apply` on `axis=1` by a list comprehension when you can.

```
# apply
2.58 s ± 33.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# list comprehension
127 ms ± 7.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# json_normalize + indexing lookup
811 ms ± 46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# groupby.transform
237 ms ± 3.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```